# How end edit of a cell, changing its content when it's clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have changed a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` to contain a string at the right of the CheckBox that reflects the CheckBox value. When it's `true`, the string is "Value1"; when it's `false` the string should change to "Value2".

The string value is changing only after the `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` loses focus. I want the string value to change right after the CheckBox value changes. How can I do that?

For reference, this is my personalized `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` class:

```
public class MyDGVCheckBoxCell : DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
{
    public static string TRUE_VALUE = "Excitada";
    public static string FALSE_VALUE = "Monitorada";

    public MyDGVCheckBoxCell(bool isExcitada)
    {
        FalseValue = FALSE_VALUE;
        TrueValue = TRUE_VALUE;
        Value = isExcitada ? TRUE_VALUE : FALSE_VALUE;
    }

    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates elementState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, elementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);

        Rectangle contentBounds = this.GetContentBounds(rowIndex);

        Point stringLocation = new Point();

        stringLocation.Y = cellBounds.Y + 4;
        stringLocation.X = cellBounds.X + contentBounds.Right + 1;

        graphics.DrawString(this.Value.ToString(), Control.DefaultFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, stringLocation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will usually find an event for the checked case. You can modify the string in that event.

Here is more information on the event.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/38f26111-671f-457d-a460-fd5e19b16378

Answer (score 0):

I use the event `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` to manage `CommitEdit`

here is a sample:

```
    void dgv_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgv.Columns[dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn))
        {
            if (dgv.Columns[dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName.StartsWith("_nodb_"))
            {
                dgv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            }
        }            
    }
```